# Are add() and appendChild() the same for select DOM objects?

Tags: javascript, dom, select, object

I'm working on a small web application that changes the contents of a select drop-down.

I was wondering if appendChild() and add() both accomplish the same task on a select DOM object in JavaScript?

```
var someSelect = document.getElementById('select-list');
var newOption = document.createElement('option');
someSelect.appendChild(newOption);
// The above is the same as the following?
someSelect.add(newOption);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, I believe they would accomplish the same task.

`add( )` is provided specially via the [`HTMLSelectElement` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add) specifically to add options to a `select` element and has a few extra options (such as an optional index at which to add the new `option`, etc.).

`appendChild( )` will give you a straight append of the child node.

Watch out for different implementations of both methods cross-browser: I think that would be your biggest pain point. IIRC, the IEs would cause problems when appending children to `select`s, so you might want to `add` if that method exists and fall back on `appendChild`.

Comment: Looks like that would be the best option.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be sure of cross-browser compatibility when manipulating options within a `<select>`, the surest way is to use its `options` property and populate it with `Option` objects. The following time-honoured method works in all scriptable browsers since the late 1990s:

```
var options = select.options;
options[options.length] = new Option("Option text", "option_value");
```

Comment: `options[options.length]` would be better written as `options.push()`

Comment: @Kulvar: No. `options` is not an `Array` and doesn't have a `push()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be equivalent, but here you can find a question which remarks the different implementations when you try to work with option groups:

[SELECT box: On IE item is added to OptGroup instead of root. FF ok](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22221289/1919228)

IE fails to add a new option "in the root" when there is already group inside the select element.