# How do you update all options of a select with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring

I have a map object I am placing in a Spring `ModelAndView` in my controller and forwarding to my jsp view to populate a select.  After it populates the first time, I want to replace the map object used to populate the select with a json object I am retrieving using jquery AJAX and converting to an object using jQuery.parseJSON.  Can I dynamically replace the entire contents of the select with the contents of the json object?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For actually modifying the options, you don't really need jQuery. You can clear the old options by assigning to the `length` property of the `options` property of the `SELECT` box, and then add new options via `#add` and `new Option()`.

Here are a couple of examples using jQuery for the XHR part and then doing the options directly:

#### From an array:

If you're drawing the data from an array within the object (in this case, an array identified by the property `options` on the resulting object):

JSON:

```
{
  "options": [
    {"value": "New1", "text": "New Option 1"},
    {"value": "New2", "text": "New Option 2"},
    {"value": "New3", "text": "New Option 3"}
  ]
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://jsbin.com/apici3",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    var options, index, select, option;

    // Get the raw DOM object for the select box
    select = document.getElementById('theSelect');

    // Clear the old options
    select.options.length = 0;

    // Load the new options
    options = data.options; // Or whatever source information you're working with
    for (index = 0; index < options.length; ++index) {
      option = options[index];
      select.options.add(new Option(option.text, option.value));
    }
  }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ibumu5/2)

#### Directly from an object:

If you're using the object's property names as `option` values, and the property values as the option text:

JSON:

```
{
  "new1": "New Option 1",
  "new2": "New Option 2",
  "new3": "New Option 3"
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://jsbin.com/apici3/2",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    var name, select, option;

    // Get the raw DOM object for the select box
    select = document.getElementById('theSelect');

    // Clear the old options
    select.options.length = 0;

    // Load the new options
    for (name in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        select.options.add(new Option(data[name], name));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ibumu5/3)

---

**Update**: Rather than

```
select.options.add(new Option(...));
```

you can also do:

```
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(...);
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ibumu5/4)

...which I think actually I would tend to use over the `add` method on the `options` array-like-thing (I'm not calling it an array because it has a method, `add`, that arrays don't have; and because if you use `push`, which arrays *do* have, it doesn't work).

I've tested both methods on

- IE6,7,8 (Windows)
- Chrome (Linux & Windows)
- Firefox (Linux & Windows)
- Opera (Linux & Windows)
- Safari (Windows)

...and the both work. Perhaps someone with a Mac could try Safari on OS X for me.

I'd say both ways are very, very well supported.

Comment: should be select.add(new Option(data[name], name));

Comment: if(document.all){ /*IE*/
                     select.add(new Option(data[name], name));
                    }else{
                     select.appendChild(new Option(data[name], name));
                    }

Comment: @Ritesh: Not sure I'm following you...? My example works, without branching, on all major browsers (including IE6).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder The 'add' method is available on Select object. options property is an array. There is some cross browser issue for 'add' vs. 'appendChild'. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611615/are-add-and-appendchild-the-same-for-select-dom-objects

Comment: @Ritesh: Actually, the `options` property isn't (just) an array, it has an `add` method (see my code) that works (again) in all major browsers. (Note that I'm using `add` on the `options`, not on the select element itself.) You're quite right that `appendChild` does *not* work reliably, which is why I'm not using it. Tim's method of adding via `select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(...);` *also* works on every major browser.

Comment: @Ritesh: And when I say "every major browser," I mean it; I've updated the answer with a list.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks for clarifying it. I agree with you.

Comment: @Ritesh: :-) Thanks for linking to that other question and reminding me of the `options[options.length] = ...` way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
       $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: getpolicytypeUrl ,
                data: { sirket: companyname },
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                        $('#policyshortname').append($('<option>', {
                            text: element.policyShortname
                        }));
                        $('#policyshortname').show(300);
                    });

                }
            });


        $('#policyshortname').html('refresh',true);
```