# Adding items to select (list box) of html/php through jQuery or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is it possible to add items to a select (list box) of html/php through jQuery or javascript when a specific action is triggered by another control in jQuery/javascript? *(edited by [Alex Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/611306/alex-thomas))*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, attach a suitable handler to the event of your choice. For example if you want to add new items when another control changes, you might use something like this:

```
$('#controller').change(function() {
    $('#child_select').append('<option>New option</option>');
});
```

Or alternatively, there are jQuery plugins available to make the drop down list dynamic based on the selection of another element.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add items on the client-side. For example:

```
// Get the raw DOM select element (first use jQuery
// to find it, then get the raw version via [0] 
var select = $("select[name=someField]")[0];

// Add the option
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("Third Option", "3");
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ekofa4)

See also: [*How do you update all options of a select with jquery?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022928/how-do-you-update-all-options-of-a-select-with-jquery/5023112#5023112)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the:
 `$('select').append('<option value="id" selected="selected">Text</option>');` method, via jQuery.  You can call this a number of ways (and get your data via ajax, stored objects, etc).

If you can provide a little more information of what actions you want to trigger this, I can provide a better example.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure jQuery's `append` works correctly to add options to a select box, reliably cross-browser? The raw DOM version, `appendChild`, does not, but that doesn't mean jQuery doesn't make it work under-the-covers.

Comment: I'll clarify my post, but thanks for pointing that out.  appending html works, but appending new Option('id', 'value') doesn't - thanks for the eye.