# Form - Update options with MySQL query based on first selection

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

What I want is for the 2nd set of options to change to whatever is available once a name is selected based on `date=today and name=selectedname` also

Here is the basics of the table:

```
ID | name  | location  |  Date
1  |John   | place 1   |  03-07-2015
2  |Jane   | place 2   |  03-07-2015
3  |John   | place 2   |  04-07-2015
4  |Jane   | place 2   |  04-07-2015
```

I am just not sure how to run the SQL statement

`SELECT location 
FROM table 
WHERE name = "selected name" 
  AND date = CURDATE()`  based on when Select "name" changes

Here is an example of my current code :

```html
<form name="test" id="test">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <select name="name" id="name" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
      <option value="John">John</option>
      <option value="Jane">Jane</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="location">location:</label>
    <select name="location" id="location" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
      <option value="place 1">place 1</option>
      <option value="place 2">place 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="startend">Start or Finish:</label>
    <select name="startend" id="startend" required>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select</option>
      <option value="Start">Start</option>
      <option value="End">Finish</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="submit">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

so once John selects 'John' from name selection the location select box will only contain 'Place 1' if todays date is 03-07-2015 but if todays date was 04-07-2015 then it would only contain 'Place 2'

Comment: name are repetitive. still possible. create a select box where options are `name` and values are `ID`. then on form submission you will get that id and then you can update easily.

Comment: If i understood correctly so if a name is selected then update all the rows by second selected value ?

Comment: John and John are same person same with Jane - ID just there for primary column, so basically if John was Selected today location would only show 'Place 1' but if he selected his name tomoro it would show 'Place 2'

Comment: what you said is not possible. How you can trace that today tomorrow?

Comment: Based on Current Date variable with php at the start of the page

Comment: on each day it will equals to today, never comes tomorrow.

Comment: yeah im meaning if he used the form tomoro then the other location would show instead because they will use the form each day so wanting the second option to change based on "`date=today AND name=nameselected`"

Comment: i am unable to get you what you want to say. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to select the location of John today, you just need to select based on both `name` and `date` like this:

```
SELECT location 
FROM table 
WHERE name = "John" 
  AND date = CURDATE()
```

If you want to update the second select box on-the-fly after the name is selected, you'll probably want to use ajax. [Here are some good examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022928/how-do-you-update-all-options-of-a-select-with-jquery) of how to populate a select box with an ajax call, call that code the `name` or `location` fields change with something like:

```
$("#name, #location").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "fetchData.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Next we populate the <select> with the data received...");
        }
    });
});
```

The `fetchDate.php` file is something you'll need to create. This PHP file will simply grab the correct location(s) (using the SQL examples above) and echo them out in JSON format for the JS to work with (convert a PHP array to JSON with the [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function).

You'll also ideally want to use a dedicated `names` table and just reference John's name `ID` in here, otherwise you'll hit issues when the user needs to change their name or when multiple users have the same name.

Comment: Thanks, the SQL statement parts not too much of an issue mainly how to run it when the name changes, would there be a way to do it with JQuery as i know a little bit but i know nothing about Ajax

Comment: i have a table with names and Username and email/password etc how do i reference the 2 together?

Comment: @RedSparr0w You'll want to use an `inner join`, here's [a primer](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) on how to use it and the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT location 
FROM table 
WHERE name = "John" 
  AND date = "03-07-2015"
```