# JavaScript - populate drop down list with array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array declared in a script:

```
var myArray = new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5" . . . . . "N");
```

I have a form which contains a drop down menu:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Using Javascript, how will I populate the rest of the drop down menu with the array values?  So that the options will be "Choose a number", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" . . . . . "N"?

Comment: Please post your attempt and any error message(s) you're getting. Thank you.

Answer (score 145):

You'll need to loop through your array elements, create a new DOM node for each and append it to your object:

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber");
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I've got an error `textContent & value are not a function` and the solution was to **cast** opt to String like that:

`el.textContent = String(opt);

    el.value = String(opt);`


that's in case of  **opt**  isn't _**String**_.

Comment: @AbdallahOkasha That doesn't make sense. That error would happen if you tried to use `el.textContent` like this: `el.textContent(opt)`. If you use it like in my exmaple, it doesn't matter if it's a `number` the browsers will turn it into a string.

Comment: Thanks for caring .. actually, I've tried to write `el.textContent = arr[i]` or `el.value = arr[i]` and i have got an error said: **_value_, _text_ and _textContent_ are not functions**.

Comment: @AbdallahOkasha can you reproduce a minimal example of this error on something like http://jsfiddle.net/ and share a link?

Comment: This's jsfiddle snippet @alex in this example .text function works well 
without parsing to string, however in my code it gives me an error 

i am actually using similar array of string (each contains white spaces).

https://jsfiddle.net/okasha/h1jt3yz1/2/

Comment: @AbdallahOkasha You are using `text` and not `textContent` in those examples. And both examples seem to work without giving an error.

Answer (score 69):

You can also do it with jQuery:

```
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
$('#select').empty();
$.each(options, function(i, p) {
    $('#select').append($('<option></option>').val(p).html(p));
});
```

Answer (score 19):

I used [Alex Turpin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104999/alex-turpin)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9895164/6045800) with small corrections as mentioned below:

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber"); 
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; 

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];

    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.text = opt;
    el.value = opt;

    select.add(el);
}​
```

Corrections because with the `appendChild()` function it loads when the DOM prepares. So It's not working in old (8 or lesser) IE versions. So with the corrections it's working fine.

Some notes on [the differences between `add()` and `appendChild()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611615/are-add-and-appendchild-the-same-for-select-dom-objects?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 13):

You'll first get the dropdown element from the DOM, then loop through the array, and add each element as a new option in the dropdown like this:

```js
var myArray = new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");


// Get dropdown element from DOM
var dropdown = document.getElementById("selectNumber");

// Loop through the array
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    // Append the element to the end of Array list
    dropdown[dropdown.length] = new Option(myArray[i], myArray[i]);
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

This assumes that you're not using JQuery, and you only have the basic DOM API to work with.

Comment: Note, I ran into this problem when I copy-pasted this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404526/unexpected-token-illegal-in-webkit

Comment: @NielsBrinch - Don't copy-and-paste directly from JSFiddle. :)

Comment: I actually copy-pasted from Stackovervflow, not the fiddle - but maybe the stackoverflow author copy-pasted from his own fiddle and the copy-paste got carried over! :)

Comment: @NielsBrinch - What was the error? Was it "dropdown is undefined"?

Comment: No, it was exactly the one I linked to. "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" in webkit.

Answer (score 13):

I found this also works...

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectNumber"); 
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; 

// Optional: Clear all existing options first:
select.innerHTML = "";
// Populate list with options:
for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var opt = options[i];
    select.innerHTML += "<option value=\"" + opt + "\">" + opt + "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Something like this should work:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown1");
if (dropdown) {
    for (var i=0; i < month.length;++i){    
        addOption(dropdown, month[i], month[i]);
    }
}

addOption = function(selectbox, text, value) {
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = text;
    optn.value = value;
    selectbox.options.add(optn);  
}
```

You can refer to this article for more details:
http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/list-adding.php

Answer (score 8):

```
["1","2","3","4"].forEach( function(item) { 
   const optionObj = document.createElement("option");
   optionObj.textContent = item;
   document.getElementById("myselect").appendChild(optionObj);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Using template literals would be:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4]
var options = arr.map(e=>{return `<option value="${e}">${e}</option>`})
document.getElementById("selectNumber").innerHTML = options.join('')
//document.getElementById("selectNumber").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", options);
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Beautiful, compact and simple solution.

Comment: Or even `document.getElementById("selectNumber = arr.map(val => \`<option value="${val}">${val}</option>\`);` - I would reserve the variable `e` for event

Comment: Even better! 

Comment: This results in commas in between all the option elements because you're implicitly converting the array to a string. It doesn't seem to show the commas to the end user, but still, I would replace the `= options` in this answer with `= options.join('')`

Comment: @mplungian:  another alternative for the last statement is to insert the array to the select like this:
document.getElementById("selectNumber").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", options);

Answer (score 4):

Here is my answer:

```
var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for(m = 0 ; m <= options.length-1; m++){
   var opt= document.createElement("OPTION");
   opt.text = options[m];
   opt.value = (m+1);
   if(options[m] == "5"){
    opt.selected = true;}
document.getElementById("selectNum").options.add(opt);}
```

Comment: This is a code only answer. Please add some explanation what your code is doing.

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with React and JSX, you can use the map function. Then you don't need to add DOM nodes manually.

```
const numsarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

You can map this into your `<options>` tag (within `<select>`)

```
<select>
  {numsarray.map((num) => (
    <option>{numsarray}</option>
  ))}
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var test = document.getElementById("TestOption");
var arr = ["A","B","C","D"];  
//remove options if necessary
for(var i=test.options.length- 1;i>= 0;i--) {test.remove(i);}        
//add new options
for(i in arr) {test.add(new Option(arr[i],i));}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a method to remove before append elements.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var list =["muez","devomech","solution"]
var option = "";
          for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
            option+= '<option value="'+ list[i] +'">' + list[i] + "</option>"
          
        }
        document.getElementById("deviceoption").innerHTML = option;
```

```html
<select id="deviceoption"></select>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="myForm">
<select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
    <script>
        var myArray = new Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5" . . . . . "N");
        for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {  
            document.write('<option value="' + myArray[i] +'">' + myArray[i] + '</option>');
        }
    </script>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple jQuery solution that is easy to debug:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <select id="selectNumber">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script>
  var myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
  for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    $("#selectNumber").append("<option value='" + myArray[i] + "'>" + myArray[i] + "</option>");
  }
</script>
```