# Set selectbox value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript - populate drop down list with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array)

I have following `select` box,

```
<select name="supplier" id="supplier"><option></option></select>
```

I want to set the values of this `select` box using `Javascript`. The `Javascript` variable may be a `String` or an `Array`. That means if its a `String` then there will be only one option in `select` box. And if it is an array the `select` box should contain multiple `options`. Someone please help me find the solution. Thanks in advance....

I have tried

```
document.getElementById('supplier').value="Option 1";
```

but its not working

Comment: Do you want to set the options or the value? There is a difference. The value is the selected option(s). Also, were exactly are you stuck?

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like you are asking someone to do your work more than an issue with something not working.

Comment: I have edited my question, please undo the downvotes because my reputation is too low...And thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), if you are doing a lot of DOM manipulation:

```
$("#supplier").append('<option value=1>My option</option>');
```

Without jQuery:

```
var select = document.getElementById("supplier");
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Text 1', 'Value1');
```

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for editing.Now you can cancel the down vote.right?

Comment: I can only cancel my own down votes, not those of others...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/f4yEt/

```
function addOptions(input) {
    var sel = document.getElementById("supplier");
    if (typeof input === "string") {
        input = [input];
    }
    sel.options.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        sel.options[sel.options.length] = new Option(input[i], input[i]);
        // This APPENDS options
    }
}
```

The `input` parameter can be a string or array (technically it only checks for string, to turn it into an array for iterating), and then dynamically appends an option for each item in the array.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you will need to create the  nodes inside the .

```
var select = document.getElementById('supplier');
var option = document.createElement('option');
select.add(option);
```

Here is a larger tutorial that takes IE/FF differences into account:
http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial005.html

**BUT**

I would consider using jquery for this. Sujathan's answer has the jquery.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery method for arrays

```
var array = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"];
$.each(array, function(i, value) {
  $('#supplier').append($(document.createElement('option')).attr('value', i + 1).text(value));
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NN8KS/

Answer (score 0):

```
//var varOpt = "test";
var varOpt = new Array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
var sel = document.getElementById('supplier');

if( typeof varOpt === 'string' ){
   sel.add(new Option(varOpt , varOpt));
} else {
    for(key in varOpt) {
        sel.add(new Option(varOpt[key], varOpt[key]));
    }
}
```