# how can I give an array as options to select element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select element on my HTML page. I want to populate it with an array. as we can give an array as dataprovider to comboBox in action script. I do the following

in HTML...

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Recording Mode:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="rec_mode">        
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

in javascript...

```
var videoSrcArr = new Array("option1", "option2", "option3", "option4", "option5");
```

how can I populate rec_mode element when page is loaded with VideoSrcArr? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - populate drop down list with array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array) (and various other questions).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I highly recommend you use a format like the following:

```
var options =
[
  {
    "text"  : "Option 1",
    "value" : "Value 1"
  },
  {
    "text"     : "Option 2",
    "value"    : "Value 2",
    "selected" : true
  },
  {
    "text"  : "Option 3",
    "value" : "Value 3"
  }
];

var selectBox = document.getElementById('rec_mode');

for(var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++){
  var option = options[i];
  selectBox.options.add( new Option(option.text, option.value, option.selected) );
}
```

You don't run in to the problem of having to select a default option and you can easily generate the options array dynamically.

-- UPDATE --

ES6 version of the above code:

```
let optionList = document.getElementById('rec_mode').options;
let options = [
  {
    text: 'Option 1',
    value: 'Value 1'
  },
  {
    text: 'Option 2',
    value: 'Value 2',
    selected: true
  },
  {
    text: 'Option 3',
    value: 'Value 3'
  }
];

options.forEach(option =>
  optionList.add(
    new Option(option.text, option.value, option.selected)
  )
);
```

Comment: How to get select value?

Comment: What if you want to do this with the text being the... item and the value being the index?

Comment: @haykam You could, but then you can't designate if one of them is selected. If that's not part of your requirements, no big deal. Just use an array, map the value to the first parameter and the index to the second.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend to use object instead of array it will be of great helpful and in respected manner with standards. The reason is WE can index into the object by the "key" and get the "value" . To display contents and resetting them you can follow this  [NOTES](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-add-options-html-select/)

**[CHECK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/UThAr/)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Recording Mode:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select id="rec_mode">        
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
<script>
var myobject = {
    ValueA : 'Text A',
    ValueB : 'Text B',
    ValueC : 'Text C'
};
var select = document.getElementById("rec_mode");
for(index in myobject) {
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(myobject[index], index);
}

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the simplest way to populate comboBox with an array.

```
var j = new Array("option1","option2","option3","option4","option5"),    
var options = '';

for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
   options += '<option value="' + j[i]+ '">' + j[i] + '</option>';
}
$("#rec_mode").html(options);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var videoSrcArr = new Array("option1","option2","option3","option4","option5"),
    selectEl = document.getElementById('rec_mode');


for(var i = 0; i < videoSrcArr.length; i++){
    selectEl.options.add(new Option(videoSrcArr[i], videoSrcArr[i]));
}
```

Comment: —better to use an array literal than the array constructor as it's less to type and less likely to do unexpected things (e.g. `new Array(9)` vs `[9]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way you can get array values in combo box

```js
var states = new Array();
states['India'] = new Array('Andhra Pradesh','Arunachal Pradesh','Assam','Bihar','Chhattisgarh','Goa','Gujarat','Haryana','Himachal Pradesh','Jammu and Kashmir','Jharkhand','Karnataka','Kerala','Madhya Pradesh','Maharashtra','Manipur','Meghalaya','Mizoram','Nagaland','Odisha','Punjab','Rajasthan','Sikkim','Tamil Nadu','Telangana','Tripura','Uttar Pradesh','Uttarakhand','WestBengal','Andaman and Nicobar Islands','Chandigarh','Dadra and Nagar Haveli','Daman and Diu','Lakshadweep','Puducherry'); 

function setStates() {
 var newOptions=states['India'];
 var newValues=states['India'];
 selectField = document.getElementById("state");
 selectField.options.length = 0;
 for (i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) 
 {
 selectField.options[selectField.length] = new Option(newOptions[i], newValues[i]);
 }
}
```

```html
<body  onload="setStates();"
<label>State :</label>
<select style="width:auto;" name="state" id="state">
<option value="">Please select a Country</option>
</select><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

A modern solution, using template literals:

```js
["option1", "option2", "option3", "option4", "option5"]
.forEach(op => rec_mode.innerHTML += `<option value="${op}">${op}</option>`);
```

```html
<select id="rec_mode"></select>
```