# How to add options to select element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can add the array data below into a `select` box using JavaScript or jQuery?

```
 var SHIFT_Plants = [
              { Plant: 0, PlantName: "" },
              { Plant: 2737, PlantName: "PM1" },
              { Plant: 2738, PlantName: "PM2" },
              { Plant: 2739, PlantName: "SSP" },
              { Plant: 2740, PlantName: "UT1" },
              { Plant: 2741, PlantName: "UT2" },
              { Plant: 2742, PlantName: "TW1" },
              { Plant: 2743, PlantName: "TW2" },
              { Plant: 2744, PlantName: "TW3" },
              { Plant: 2745, PlantName: "TW4" },
              { Plant: 2746, PlantName: "FL1" },
              { Plant: 2747, PlantName: "FL2" },
              { Plant: 2748, PlantName: "FL3" },
              { Plant: 2749, PlantName: "FL4" },
              { Plant: 2750, PlantName: "MS1" },
              { Plant: 2751, PlantName: "MS2" },
              { Plant: 2752, PlantName: "PY1" },
              { Plant: 2753, PlantName: "PY2" },
              { Plant: 2754, PlantName: "DDX" },
              { Plant: 2755, PlantName: "DT1" },
              { Plant: 2756, PlantName: "DT2" }
        ];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I give an array as options to select element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473207/how-can-i-give-an-array-as-options-to-select-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery as it supports a lot of functions.

Loop through the array with [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and get each array item as Object. Then access the Object with its keys e.g. `Plant` and `PlantName` to get its values.

Remember to import [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) into HTML file.

```js
$(function(){

var SHIFT_Plants = [
              { Plant: 0, PlantName: "test" },
              { Plant: 2737, PlantName: "PM1" },
              { Plant: 2738, PlantName: "PM2" },
              { Plant: 2739, PlantName: "SSP" },
              { Plant: 2740, PlantName: "UT1" },
              { Plant: 2741, PlantName: "UT2" },
              { Plant: 2742, PlantName: "TW1" },
              { Plant: 2743, PlantName: "TW2" },
              { Plant: 2744, PlantName: "TW3" },
              { Plant: 2745, PlantName: "TW4" },
              { Plant: 2746, PlantName: "FL1" },
              { Plant: 2747, PlantName: "FL2" },
              { Plant: 2748, PlantName: "FL3" },
              { Plant: 2749, PlantName: "FL4" },
              { Plant: 2750, PlantName: "MS1" },
              { Plant: 2751, PlantName: "MS2" },
              { Plant: 2752, PlantName: "PY1" },
              { Plant: 2753, PlantName: "PY2" },
              { Plant: 2754, PlantName: "DDX" },
              { Plant: 2755, PlantName: "DT1" },
              { Plant: 2756, PlantName: "DT2" }
        ];
        
        $.each(SHIFT_Plants, function( key, value ) {
                    
          var opt = "<option value="+ value.Plant +" >"+ value.PlantName +"</option>";
          
          $('#test').append(opt);
          
        });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Download jQuery from here](https://jquery.com/download/)

This is slightly faster and cleaner.

```
 $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {   
         $('#mySelect')
             .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value",key)
                        .text(value)); 
    });
```

**Adding multiple options**

```
var newOptions = {
    'red' : 'Red',
    'blue' : 'Blue',
    'green' : 'Green',
    'yellow' : 'Yellow'
};
var selectedOption = 'green';

var select = $('#example');
if(select.prop) {
  var options = select.prop('options');
}
else {
  var options = select.attr('options');
}
$('option', select).remove();

$.each(newOptions, function(val, text) {
    options[options.length] = new Option(text, val);
});
select.val(selectedOption);
```

Comment: Explanations are always useful, even if the code is right, understanding why is nice, too.