# drop down list items taken from the java script

Tags: javascript

```
 <select id="myList" onchange="favBrowser()">

 <option> var x</option>
 <option> var y</option>  


</select>

<script>
   var x="google";   var y="firefox";
 </script>
```

my question is , how to take the option's values from javascript

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think he ment he want to fill the options by Script

this can be done by

```
<select id="myDropdown">

</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function fillDropDown() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById('myDropdown');

        for (var i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
            var myNewOption = new Option();
            myNewOption.value = i;
            myNewOption.text = "my " + i.toString() + " option...";
            ddl.options.add(myNewOption);
        }
    }

    fillDropDown();
</script>
```

Cheers.

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanx , yes thats wat i need

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by writing

```
function favBrowser(){
 var sel = document.getElementById("myList");
 var value =sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;  
 window.alert(value);
   }
```

Comment: no this is wrong , i need the option value to show in the drop down list

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply more information about what it is you really want to do. If what you want is to take the selected value, then take a look at this question

[Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript)