# Filling out Combobox Using JSON value

Tags: javascript, html, json, prototypejs

Hello I have a following html

```
<select id="fld_base_profile_id" defaultValue="-1" class="m-wrap span10" field="fld_base_profile_id" appEditor="true"></select>
```

I have this in my ajax

```
$result['analyze_type'][]   = array ("id" => $row[idatabase::FIELD_ID], "name" => $row[idatabase::FIELD_PROFILE_NAME]);
echo json_encode($result);
```

and in js part (by the way i'm using Prototype.js) :

```
var JSON    = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
```

In console, my JSON.analyze_type looks like this

```
Array[1]
0: Object
id: "939"
name: "Reaktif İndüktif Kontrolü Ana Profili"
```

The question is, how can i parse this JSON data so it can change my html like

```
<option value="id">name</option>  ??
```

EDIT: Solution:

```
this.baseProfile    = $("fld_base_profile_id");

var JSON    = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
    this.type   = JSON.analyze_type;
    for(var i = 0; i < JSON.analyze_type.length; i++) {
        var profile = JSON.analyze_type[i];
        var opt     = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value   = profile.id;
        opt.text    = profile.name;
        this.baseProfile.appendChild(opt);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var el = document.getElementById('fld_base_profile_id');

for(var i = 0; i < JSON.length; i++) {
    var profile = JSON[i],
        opt = document.createElement("option");

    opt.id = profile.id;
    opt.value = profile.name;
    el.appendChild(opt);
}​
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made some modifications based on your code and it works like a charm

Comment: Nice to hear, please let me know if the code have any mistakes, I'll fix it.

Comment: Sorry, that is my fault. I didn't notice that **analyze_type** is root object of your json.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in a much cleaner way

Firstly make sure you are passing the `Content-Type: application/json` header in your JSON response - All of the Ajax methods in Prototype will automatically process the response as JSON and put it into `transport.responseJSON`

Then your javascript can clean up to this

```
this.baseProfile    = $("fld_base_profile_id");

var type = transport.responseJSON.analyze_type;

type.each(function(item){
    var option = new Element('option',{'value':item.id}).update(item.name);
    this.baseProfile.insert(option);
},this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.Parse to turn the JSON you get into an object. then you can loop over the items, assign each one to an `<option>` object and then append them to the select.

[JavaScript - populate drop down list with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array) explains how to create the option tags.