# How can I create an option element using javascript and set it's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
const currencies = [
  {
    id: 'USD', name: 'US Dollars'
  }, {
    id: 'UGX', name: 'Ugandan Shillings'
  }, {
    id: 'KES', name: 'Kenyan Shillings'
  }, {
    id: 'GHS', name: 'Ghanian Cedi'
  }, {
    id: 'ZAR', name: 'South African Rand'
  }
];
```

I have an issue with my code. I want to create an option element using javascript. I have done something like this below. What is my issue?

I want each item in the currencies arrays to populate into populateCurrencies function. And it should also create an option element. And also set it's value to the item id.

```
const populateCurrencies = () => {  

            var ans = document.getElementById('USD').value;
}
```

Comment: what's the output you want ?

Comment: I want when users click an option and the value of  what the user selected should show in the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - populate drop down list with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array) and [Filling out Combobox Using JSON value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560054)

Answer (score 0):

it has to do with DOM manipulation;

```
currencies.forEach((x)=>{
let selectElt = document.querySelector('.select-text');
let newElt = document.createElement('option');
let newText = document.createTextNode(x.name);
newElt.setAttribute('value', 'x.id');
newElt.appendChild(newText);
selectElt.appendChild(newElt);
})
```