# populate number array with dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

I have found several links to populate a dropdown list with an array but none of them work for me. Some links I have tried include:

This similar Stack Overflow question: 
[JavaScript - populate drop down list with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array)

This similar situation:

Javascript:

```
var cuisines = ["Chinese","Indian"];     

var sel = document.getElementById('CuisineList');
for(var i = 0; i < cuisines.length; i++) {
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.innerHTML = cuisines[i];
opt.value = cuisines[i];
sel.appendChild(opt);
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<select id="CuisineList"></select>
```

But nothing is working. My goal is to populate a dropdown list from an external javascript array with values 0 to 255 so they can be used to come up with an RGB scheme. This is similar to the question that has been linked, but the linked question does not work when I copy and paste it into my text editor and preview it in Chrome.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Did you just try it out in the editor on the website? That works for me but when I copy and paste it into my text editor and then preview it, it doesn't work.

Comment: In that case check browser console for errors.

Comment: Did you correctly loaded the `js` file into HTML ?

Comment: Yes I correctly linked the external javascript file, I tested that.

Comment: Script should be added in document.ready event or after `<select id="CuisineList"></select>`

Comment: Did you put this code inside this window.onload = function(){ ... }

Just to ensure that the code is correctly executed after the page is completely loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

i think your dom not ready when script executed

```js
function ready() {
     var cuisines = ["Chinese","Indian"];     

     var sel = document.getElementById('CuisineList');
     for(var i = 0; i < cuisines.length; i++) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.innerHTML = cuisines[i];
      opt.value = cuisines[i];
      sel.appendChild(opt);
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

```html
<select id="CuisineList"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var cuisines = ["Chinese","Indian"];
var innerData = '';
for(var i = 0; i < cuisines.length; i++) {
    innerData += '<option value="' + 'cuisines[i]' + '">' + 'cuisines[i]' + '</option>';
}
document.getElementById('CuisineList').innerHTML = innerData;
```