# How to loop JSON in API use Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have a json located in http://example.com/json

The result of json is like this :

```
{"result":[{"id":"1","lob_group_desc":"ENTERPRISE"},{"id":"2","lob_group_desc":"SME"}]}
```

How to loop them in `<select>`

What I expected was like this :

```
<select class="form-control" id="component">
   <option>ENTERPRISE</option>
   <option>SME</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array

Comment: @SatishKumar what i want is using Vue.js :\

Comment: Yes I know , I shared the link for reference. You can get an idea from that link.

Comment: What you can do is parse the Json data and form an array of **lob_group_desc** . Then you can loop through it in html and add it as option to your select.