# how to populate date from database using html nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

I want to populate dropdown field in htlm page from mongodb rather than hardcode values

I'm using below stack of technologies:
1) EJS/CSS
2) NodeJS
3) Mongodb

I have created a page where user can create new records. This page having few dropdown fields like Area which should fetch values from collection - Area-  of mongodb. For now I have done hardcode to populate the values but I want the values being fetched from database.

Could you please guide me how to achieve with sample code.

Appreciate your response.

Regards,
Parag

```
    <tr>
                    <td>Component Area </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="comparea" /></td>

                </tr>
```

I want to populate this area field from mongodb collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that. Did not test this, but you surely can send array through ejs variable and iterate it on page.

In your router

```
app.get('/data', async (req,res)=>{

let mongoData = await db.yourDb.find(query here);
res.render('data.ejs',{data:mongoData})
})
```

now your variable <%=data%> is available on page. You may iterate it, or take out for html variable like

```
<script> var data = '<%=data%>' </script>
```

How to populate select with options check this [solved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array)

Comment: I updated my code as 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token catch in C:\NodeJS Project\crud\node-crud\views\employees\create.ejs while compiling ejs
I added below code
<% if(Area.length>0) { %>
    
     <% for (var i=0;i<Area.length;i++){ %>
       <tr>
        <td>Component Area </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="comp_area" value="<%= Area[i]%>"/></td>
        
       </tr>
      % } %>
      
      
    <% } %>

Comment: so it is as it reads, you have a mistake in your code and it is YOUR mistake

Comment: I agreed, but putting <input type="text"> inside loop is creating textbox as many times as the loop runs... What I'm looking is the dropdown field area which should be populated with the values given in the render

Please help!!!!

Comment: I don'e see any updated answer. Could you please post your answer once again.
appreciate your help.

Comment: Please refresh it

Comment: When I use <script> var data = '<%=data%>' </script> then the value of variable data remains null but in actual '<%=data%>' is not null and i have confirmed it using console.log.

Appreciate if you can give me tested code so I can finish my development work.

Comment: find this code <script> var data = '<%=data%>' </script> in your chrome dev tools -> elements you will see it not null, but a string of data.

Comment: I have seen in chrome in inspect element--> debug and it is showing me var data = ' '

Comment: that means that you're not passing it via ejs. Try adding <% console.log('data: ', data) %> to your code and check chrome dev console, if it shows no data in console, that means ejs has not received any data from your router.

Comment: before rendering you i have put console.log("Values of data is :" + areas);
res.sender("create", {areas: areas});
This console.log gives me output and I can see all the values but somehow when i tried to use it in ejs then it is showing me null

Comment: 1. res.sender or res.render? Be more accurate!
2. I told you to add <% console.log('data: ', data) %> to your code, did you do it? I do not want router console.log, but browser console.log!

Comment: Shall I add <% console.log('data: ', data) %> in my .js file or in ejs?

Comment: ejs of course! You can't use <%%> in js! Man you should spend more time reading docs, it's all there.

Comment: Yes it is printing when i put <% console.log('data: ', data) %> in ejs file. but if I put it inside <script>   </script> then not getting any value

Comment: and it's not supposed to. You really should start from scratch, read the docs, google a lot and get profficient. Currently asking questions here you're just wasting everybody's time.