# How to create dropdown from array of object?

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have this JSON

```
let array = [
    {
        "Ids": "Sec 1",
        "details": [
          {
            "id": "5ae82",
            "Name": "John",
            "currency": "$",
            "amount": "100"
          },
          {
            "id": "5ae821",
            "Name": "Henary",
            "currency": "$",
            "amount": "100"
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Ids": "Sec 2",
        "details": [
          {
            "id": "5ae83",
            "Name": "Raes",
            "currency": "$",
            "amount": "100"
          },
          {
            "id": "5ae821",
            "Name": "Jass",
            "currency": "$",
            "amount": "100"
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Ids": "Sec 3",
        "details": [
          {
            "id": "5ae831",
            "Name": "Charles",
            "currency": "$",
            "amount": "100"
          },
          {
            "id": "5ae841",
            "Name": "Twitter",
            "currency": "$",
            "amount": "100"
          }
        ]
    },  
]
```

How can I create a dropdown such that all the `Ids` should be in the dropdown list based on the dropdown selection show its details? using javascript.

The problem I am facing is how can I create a dropdown from the array of objects.

```
let dd = document.getElementById("selectdd");
dd.innerHTML = array.map((item) =>
  <option key={item.Ids} id=`${item.Ids}`>${item.Ids}</option>
);
```

How can I display the details based on ids selected?

Comment: Pls show us what you have tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript - populate drop down list with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array)

Answer (score 1):

You are entering an array to the innerHTML which is meant to get string, add a join('') at the assignment.
You should return a string for each option, so note where the ticks are.

You also want to use value property and not key or id.

```
let dd = document.getElementById("selectdd");
dd.innerHTML = array.map((item) =>
    `<option value="${item.Ids}">${item.Ids}</option>`
).join('');
```

If you want any item to be selected by default, use the selected property on the .

Answer (score 0):

**What's not?**

Unless you're using jsx, you can't inject **elements** in js code. Even if you'd, it wouldn't be possible to assign it to `innerHTML`.

**What's yes?**

Since `innerHTML` is `string`, you can map objects (`"<option>..</option>"`) into strings and then `join()` them into a single string, like this:

```js
array.map((item) =>
  `<option key={item.Ids} id="${item.Ids}">${item.Ids}</option>`
).join('')
```

```js
let array = [{
    "Ids": "Sec 1",
    "details": [{
        "id": "5ae82",
        "Name": "John",
        "currency": "$",
        "amount": "100"
      },
      {
        "id": "5ae821",
        "Name": "Henary",
        "currency": "$",
        "amount": "100"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Ids": "Sec 2",
    "details": [{
        "id": "5ae83",
        "Name": "Raes",
        "currency": "$",
        "amount": "100"
      },
      {
        "id": "5ae821",
        "Name": "Jass",
        "currency": "$",
        "amount": "100"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Ids": "Sec 3",
    "details": [{
        "id": "5ae831",
        "Name": "Charles",
        "currency": "$",
        "amount": "100"
      },
      {
        "id": "5ae841",
        "Name": "Twitter",
        "currency": "$",
        "amount": "100"
      }
    ]
  },
]

let dd = document.getElementById("selectdd");
dd.innerHTML = array.map((item) =>
  `<option key={item.Ids} id="${item.Ids}">${item.Ids}</option>`
).join('');

dd.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const {value} = e.target;
  const selectedItem = array.find(item => item.Ids === value);
  console.log(selectedItem);
});
```

```html
<select id="selectdd"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mosh Feu, actually the main problem  is based on the selection in dropdown how can I show and hide its ```details``` array of object

Comment: I've updated the answer. Basically, you have the item's id in the `change` event, you just need to `find` the items based on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this logic and extend it based on your requirement.

```
let selectElement = document.getElementById("selectdd");

array.forEach(item=>{
  const option = document.createElement("option");
  option.setAttribute("id",item.Ids);
  option.textContent = item.Ids;
  selectElement.appendChild(option);
  console.log(option);
});
```

**Codepen.io Link:**  https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/OJRvdGe

Comment: The above answer will show you the item.Ids in your code :) Then every element in the array has another another. You can extend the logic as per your requirement... :)