# HTML/JS: Making a dropdown menu from object

Tags: javascript, html, object

[Context]

I'm trying to build a RailRoadsOnline Train Builder website. Where you can select you locomotive and wagons. Then it will calculate if you can make certain grades or not. I'm planning on adding more features later but basics first. This is my first project I'm doing with HTML/JS. I do have experience in C/C++/Py/VHDL.

[Problem]

I'm having issues generating a dropdown list generated by a button, this to have the amount of locs/wagons dynamic and not hard coded.
When I pres the button I want it to make a dropdown list which gets its content list from an object. The dropdown list must show the Display_Name value but return the key when read from. Object example (Abstract/example value)`{Important_Key_Name_I_Need_Later: {Display_Name: "The Name", ...}, Porter_1: {Display_Name: "Porter 1", Mass: 7242, Length: 4, Tractive_Effort: 12.8}, ...}` So the when you would select *Porter 1* in code it would return/read out as *Porter_1*

I've adapted my code from this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array) which worked but now that I'm generating the entire dropdown it breaks.

Here is the code, I'm sorry it is a bit much:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Web Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="button" id="Calculate" value="Calculate">
    <p> Total Weight</p>
    <p id="Loc_Sel">Selected Loc</p>

    <input type="button" id="Add_Locomotive" value="Add a locomotive">
    <input type="button" id="Add_Wagon" value="Add a wagon">
    <input type="button" id="Reset" value="Reset">

</form>
</script>
<div id="Button_Div"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Locomotives
    let Locomotives = {
        Porter_1: {Mass: 7242, Length: 4, Tractive_Effort: 12.8, Display_Name: "Porter 1"},
        Porter_2: {Mass: 8145, Length: 4.8, Tractive_Effort: 12.8, Display_Name: "Porter 2"},
        Montezuma: {Mass: 14969, Length: 11, Tractive_Effort: 16.2, Display_Name: "Montezuma"},
        Shay: {Mass: 21754, Length: 8.1, Tractive_Effort: 26.2, Display_Name: "Shay"},
        Tenmile: {Mass: 19848, Length: 11.8, Tractive_Effort: 37.7, Display_Name: "Tenmile"},
        Eureka: {Mass:17164 , Length: 13.1, Tractive_Effort: 25, Display_Name: "Eureka"},
        Glenbrook: {Mass: 17128, Length: 13.5, Tractive_Effort: 34.1, Display_Name: "Glenbrook"},
        DRGW_Class_48: {Mass: 14969, Length: 7.7, Tractive_Effort: 41.7, Display_Name: "D&RGW Class 48"},
        Mosca: {Mass: 25348, Length: 13.8, Tractive_Effort: 38.3, Display_Name: "Mosca"},
        Cooke_Mogul: {Mass: 26388, Length: 15.1, Tractive_Effort: 52.8, Display_Name: "Cooke Mogul"},
        Heisler: {Mass: 28064, Length: 9.1, Tractive_Effort: 57.9, Display_Name: "Heisler"},
        Ruby_Basin: {Mass: 33042, Length: 10.3, Tractive_Effort: 60.1, Display_Name: "Ruby Basin"},
        Cooke_Consilidation: {Mass: 26706, Length: 15.1, Tractive_Effort: 59.9, Display_Name: "Cooke Consilidation"},
        Climax: {Mass: 24194, Length: 8.7, Tractive_Effort: 76.6, Display_Name: "Climax"},
        DRG_Class_70: {Mass: 15468, Length: 15.6, Tractive_Effort: 68.8, Display_Name: "D&RG Class 70"},
        ETWNC_2_8_0: {Mass: 16545, Length: 16.2, Tractive_Effort: 73.6, Display_Name: "ET&WNC 2-8-0"}
    };
    //Wagons
    let Wagons = {
        No_Car: {Mass: 0, Length: 0, Display_Name: "No_Car", Cargo: {}},
        Skeleton_Car: {Mass: 3000, Length: 6.4, Display_Name: "Skeleton Car", Cargo: {Logs: 5}},
        Flatcar_Rounds: {Mass: 3800, Length: 8.4, Display_Name: "Flatcar Rounds", Cargo: {Logs: 6, Steel_Pipes: 9}},
        Flatcar_Stakes: {Mass: 4000, Length: 8.4, Display_Name: "Flatcar Stakes", Cargo: {Lumber: 6, Beams: 3, Raw_Iron: 3, Rails: 10}},
        Flatcar_Bulkhead: {Mass: 4100, Length: 8.4, Display_Name: "Flatcar Bulkhead", Cargo: {Cordwood: 6, Oil_Barrels: 46}},
        Hopper: {Mass: 6000, Length: 8.2, Display_Name: "Hopper", Cargo: {Iron_ore: 10, Coal_Ore: 10}},
        EBT_Hopper: {Mass: 6000, Length: 7.75, Display_Name: "EBT Hopper", Cargo: {Iron_ore: 8, Coal_Ore: 10}},
        Tanker: {Mass: 13968, Length: 8.1, Display_Name: "Tanker", Cargo: {Crude_Oil: 12}},
        Coffin_Tank_Car: {Mass: 14250, Length: 10, Display_Name: "Coffin Tank Car", Cargo: {Crude_Oil: 8}},
        Box_Car: {Mass: 7938, Length: 8.1, Display_Name: "Box Car", Cargo: {Tool_Crates: 32}},
        Stock_Car: {Mass: 8000, Length: 9.4, Display_Name: "Stock Car", Cargo: {Tool_Crates: 32}},
        Bobber_Caboose: {Mass: 5400, Length: 6.8, Display_Name: "Bobber Caboose", Cargo: {}},
        DSPP_Waycar: {Mass: 5000, Length: 6.1, Display_Name: "DSP&P Waycar", Cargo: {}},
        Snow_Plow: {Mass: 6000, Length: 6, Display_Name: "Snow Plow", Cargo: {}}
    };
    //Cargo Types
    let Cargo_Types = {
        Logs: {Money: 10, Mass: 2000, Display_Name: "Logs"},
        Cordwood: {Money: 10, Mass: 1200, Display_Name: "Cordwood"},
        Beams: {Money: 24, Mass: 1410, Display_Name: "Beams"},
        Lumber: {Money: 12, Mass: 1350, Display_Name: "Lumber"},
        Iron_Ore: {Money: 20, Mass: 1000, Display_Name: "Iron Ore"},
        Coal_Ore: {Money: 15, Mass: 1000, Display_Name: "Coal Ore"},
        Raw_Iron: {Money: 25, Mass: 1490, Display_Name: "Raw Iron"},
        Rails: {Money: 25, Mass: 900, Display_Name: "Rails"},
        Steel_Pipes: {Money: 40, Mass: 1800, Display_Name: "Steel Pipes"},
        Tool_Crates: {Money: 30, Mass: 100, Display_Name: "Tool Crates"},
        Crude_Oil: {Money: 25, Mass: 1000, Display_Name: "Crude Oil"},
        Oil_Barrels: {Money: 40, Mass: 137, Display_Name: "Oil Barrels"}
    };

    let Vehicles = {Loc: -1, Wag: -1};
    
    const Button_Calculate = document.getElementById('Calculate');
    const Button_Add_Locomotive = document.getElementById('Add_Locomotive');
    const Button_Add_Wagon = document.getElementById('Add_Wagon');
    const Button_Reset = document.getElementById('Reset');
    
    //This is the adapted version of the linked code.
    function Mk_DropDown(Id, Dictionairy){
        var Options = document.getElementById(Id);
        Object.keys(Dictionairy).forEach(key => {
            Options.appendChild(new Option(Dictionairy[key]['Display_Name'], key));
        });
    }
    

    //This function should not becausing issues, just included for completeness.
    function changeText(element, value) {
        document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = value;
    }
    
    //This function should not becausing issues, just included for completeness.
    function Calculate_Train_Weight() {
        let Weight = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < Vehicles['Loc']; i++) {
            Locomotives[document.getElementById("Select_Loc_" + i).value]['Mass'];
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < Vehicles['Wag']; i++) {
            Wagons[document.getElementById("Select_Wagon_" + i).value]['Mass'];
        }
        return Weight;
    }

    //This function should not becausing issues, just included for completeness.
    function Calculate() {
        changeText('Loc_Sel', Calculate_Train_Weight());
    }

    function Add_Locomotive() {
        Vehicles['Loc']++;
        console.log(Vehicles['Loc']);
        document.getElementById("Button_Div").innerHTML = "<select> id=\"Select_Locomotive_" + Vehicles['Loc'] + "<option>Choose a locomotive</option></select>" + document.getElementById("Button_Div").innerHTML
//Is doing it once when creating new box enough or should it loop through al existing dropdowns as well?
        Mk_DropDown("Select_Loc_" + Vehicles['Loc'], Locomotives); 
    }

    function Add_Wagon() {
        Vehicles['Wag']++;
        document.getElementById("Button_Div").innerHTML += "<select> id=\"Select_Wagon_" + Vehicles['Wag'] + "<option>Choose a wagon</option></select>"
//Is doing it once when creating new box enough or should it loop through al existing dropdowns as well?
        for(let i = 0; i < Vehicles['Wag']; i++) {
            Mk_DropDown("Select_Wagon_" + i, Wagons); 
        }
    }

    //This function works but feels like a hack, so if you have suggestions for this feel free to mention it!
    function Reset() {
        document.getElementById("Button_Div").innerHTML = "";
        Vehicles['Loc'] = 0;
        Vehicles['Wag'] = 0;
    }

    Button_Add_Locomotive.addEventListener('click', Add_Locomotive);
    Button_Add_Wagon.addEventListener('click', Add_Wagon);
    Button_Reset.addEventListener('click', Reset);
    Button_Calculate.addEventListener('click', Calculate);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Breaks" in what way?  In the browser's development tools, are there any errors on the console?  When you use the browser's script debugger, which operation first fails or produces an unexpected result?

Comment: Your HTML as posted is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly this implementation is a little jank, but your main problem is the way you're concatenating strings. You're concatenating the strings in a way that makes `Mk_DropDown` unable to find the element with the `id` you've passed.

In `Add_Locomotive` you need to pass an `id` that's consistent with what you're assigning to the `select` elements. You've assigned the `id`s to iterate for each button press with the prefix `Select_Locomotive_[someindex]`. I'm going to change that to `Select_Loc_[someindex]` like what's passed into `Mk_DropDown`.

The second problem is that the `id` attribute needs to be inside the leading `select` tag.

The third problem is that the backslash exception needs to close the `id` as well as start.

A revised `Add_Locomotive` could look like:

```js
function Add_Locomotive() {
        Vehicles['Loc']++;
        console.log(Vehicles['Loc']);
        document.getElementById("Button_Div").innerHTML = "<select " + "id=\"Select_Loc_" + Vehicles['Loc'] + "\" >" + "<option>Choose a locomotive</option></select>" + document.getElementById("Button_Div").innerHTML
        Mk_DropDown("Select_Loc_" + Vehicles['Loc'], Locomotives);
}
```

To simplify further I'd use string interpolation:

```js
function Add_Locomotive() {
        Vehicles['Loc']++;
        console.log(Vehicles['Loc']);
        document.getElementById("Button_Div").innerHTML = `<select id="Select_Loc_${Vehicles['Loc']}" > <option>Choose a locomotive</option></select>` + document.getElementById("Button_Div").innerHTML
        Mk_DropDown("Select_Loc_" + Vehicles['Loc'], Locomotives);
}
```

I can't tell if you're just trying stuff out in your implementation for `Add_Wagon` or if you're testing performance, but you need to change your equality check in the `for loop` to `i <= Vehicles['Wag']` or it won't run because adding the first wagon will make `Vehicles['Wag'] === 0`, which is not less than `0` and your loop only runs when `i < 0` .

```js
function Add_Wagon() {
        Vehicles['Wag']++;
        document.getElementById("Button_Div").innerHTML += `<select id="Select_Wagon_${Vehicles['Wag']}" > <option>Choose a wagon</option></select>`
        for (let i = 0; i <= Vehicles['Wag']; i++) {
            Mk_DropDown("Select_Wagon_" + i, Wagons);
        }
}
```

Lastly, your `Reset` function will break the `Add_Wagon` function because it resets the `Vehicles` object to `{"Wag": 0, "Loc": 0}` which is not a reset since it was initiated with `{"Wag": -1, "Loc": -1}`. Doing the loop in `Add_Wag` won't work because you will run `Reset`, run `Add_Wagon` and append a child with `id="Select_Wagon_1"` then you will run the loop and the first argument to be passed to `Mk_DropDown` is `Mk_DropDown("Select_Wagon_0", Wagons)` which is not a child in the DOM.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Web Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="button" id="Calculate" value="Calculate">
        <p> Total Weight</p>
        <p id="Loc_Sel">Selected Loc</p>

        <input type="button" id="Add_Locomotive" value="Add a locomotive">
        <input type="button" id="Add_Wagon" value="Add a wagon">
        <input type="button" id="Reset" value="Reset">

    </form>
    </script>
    <div id="Button_Div"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Locomotives
        let Locomotives = {
            Porter_1: { Mass: 7242, Length: 4, Tractive_Effort: 12.8, Display_Name: "Porter 1" },
            Porter_2: { Mass: 8145, Length: 4.8, Tractive_Effort: 12.8, Display_Name: "Porter 2" },
            Montezuma: { Mass: 14969, Length: 11, Tractive_Effort: 16.2, Display_Name: "Montezuma" },
            Shay: { Mass: 21754, Length: 8.1, Tractive_Effort: 26.2, Display_Name: "Shay" },
            Tenmile: { Mass: 19848, Length: 11.8, Tractive_Effort: 37.7, Display_Name: "Tenmile" },
            Eureka: { Mass: 17164, Length: 13.1, Tractive_Effort: 25, Display_Name: "Eureka" },
            Glenbrook: { Mass: 17128, Length: 13.5, Tractive_Effort: 34.1, Display_Name: "Glenbrook" },
            DRGW_Class_48: { Mass: 14969, Length: 7.7, Tractive_Effort: 41.7, Display_Name: "D&RGW Class 48" },
            Mosca: { Mass: 25348, Length: 13.8, Tractive_Effort: 38.3, Display_Name: "Mosca" },
            Cooke_Mogul: { Mass: 26388, Length: 15.1, Tractive_Effort: 52.8, Display_Name: "Cooke Mogul" },
            Heisler: { Mass: 28064, Length: 9.1, Tractive_Effort: 57.9, Display_Name: "Heisler" },
            Ruby_Basin: { Mass: 33042, Length: 10.3, Tractive_Effort: 60.1, Display_Name: "Ruby Basin" },
            Cooke_Consilidation: { Mass: 26706, Length: 15.1, Tractive_Effort: 59.9, Display_Name: "Cooke Consilidation" },
            Climax: { Mass: 24194, Length: 8.7, Tractive_Effort: 76.6, Display_Name: "Climax" },
            DRG_Class_70: { Mass: 15468, Length: 15.6, Tractive_Effort: 68.8, Display_Name: "D&RG Class 70" },
            ETWNC_2_8_0: { Mass: 16545, Length: 16.2, Tractive_Effort: 73.6, Display_Name: "ET&WNC 2-8-0" }
        };
        //Wagons
        let Wagons = {
            No_Car: { Mass: 0, Length: 0, Display_Name: "No_Car", Cargo: {} },
            Skeleton_Car: { Mass: 3000, Length: 6.4, Display_Name: "Skeleton Car", Cargo: { Logs: 5 } },
            Flatcar_Rounds: { Mass: 3800, Length: 8.4, Display_Name: "Flatcar Rounds", Cargo: { Logs: 6, Steel_Pipes: 9 } },
            Flatcar_Stakes: { Mass: 4000, Length: 8.4, Display_Name: "Flatcar Stakes", Cargo: { Lumber: 6, Beams: 3, Raw_Iron: 3, Rails: 10 } },
            Flatcar_Bulkhead: { Mass: 4100, Length: 8.4, Display_Name: "Flatcar Bulkhead", Cargo: { Cordwood: 6, Oil_Barrels: 46 } },
            Hopper: { Mass: 6000, Length: 8.2, Display_Name: "Hopper", Cargo: { Iron_ore: 10, Coal_Ore: 10 } },
            EBT_Hopper: { Mass: 6000, Length: 7.75, Display_Name: "EBT Hopper", Cargo: { Iron_ore: 8, Coal_Ore: 10 } },
            Tanker: { Mass: 13968, Length: 8.1, Display_Name: "Tanker", Cargo: { Crude_Oil: 12 } },
            Coffin_Tank_Car: { Mass: 14250, Length: 10, Display_Name: "Coffin Tank Car", Cargo: { Crude_Oil: 8 } },
            Box_Car: { Mass: 7938, Length: 8.1, Display_Name: "Box Car", Cargo: { Tool_Crates: 32 } },
            Stock_Car: { Mass: 8000, Length: 9.4, Display_Name: "Stock Car", Cargo: { Tool_Crates: 32 } },
            Bobber_Caboose: { Mass: 5400, Length: 6.8, Display_Name: "Bobber Caboose", Cargo: {} },
            DSPP_Waycar: { Mass: 5000, Length: 6.1, Display_Name: "DSP&P Waycar", Cargo: {} },
            Snow_Plow: { Mass: 6000, Length: 6, Display_Name: "Snow Plow", Cargo: {} }
        };
        //Cargo Types
        let Cargo_Types = {
            Logs: { Money: 10, Mass: 2000, Display_Name: "Logs" },
            Cordwood: { Money: 10, Mass: 1200, Display_Name: "Cordwood" },
            Beams: { Money: 24, Mass: 1410, Display_Name: "Beams" },
            Lumber: { Money: 12, Mass: 1350, Display_Name: "Lumber" },
            Iron_Ore: { Money: 20, Mass: 1000, Display_Name: "Iron Ore" },
            Coal_Ore: { Money: 15, Mass: 1000, Display_Name: "Coal Ore" },
            Raw_Iron: { Money: 25, Mass: 1490, Display_Name: "Raw Iron" },
            Rails: { Money: 25, Mass: 900, Display_Name: "Rails" },
            Steel_Pipes: { Money: 40, Mass: 1800, Display_Name: "Steel Pipes" },
            Tool_Crates: { Money: 30, Mass: 100, Display_Name: "Tool Crates" },
            Crude_Oil: { Money: 25, Mass: 1000, Display_Name: "Crude Oil" },
            Oil_Barrels: { Money: 40, Mass: 137, Display_Name: "Oil Barrels" }
        };

        let Vehicles = { Loc: -1, Wag: -1 };

        const Button_Calculate = document.getElementById('Calculate');
        const Button_Add_Locomotive = document.getElementById('Add_Locomotive');
        const Button_Add_Wagon = document.getElementById('Add_Wagon');
        const Button_Reset = document.getElementById('Reset');

        //This is the adapted version of the linked code.
        function Mk_DropDown(Id, Dictionairy) {
            var Options = document.getElementById(Id);
            Object.keys(Dictionairy).forEach(key => {
                Options.appendChild(new Option(Dictionairy[key]['Display_Name'], key));
            });
        }


        //This function should not becausing issues, just included for completeness.
        function changeText(element, value) {
            document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = value;
        }

        //This function should not becausing issues, just included for completeness.
        function Calculate_Train_Weight() {
            let Weight = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < Vehicles['Loc']; i++) {
                Locomotives[document.getElementById("Select_Loc_" + i).value]['Mass'];
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < Vehicles['Wag']; i++) {
                Wagons[document.getElementById("Select_Wagon_" + i).value]['Mass'];
            }
            return Weight;
        }

        //This function should not becausing issues, just included for completeness.
        function Calculate() {
            changeText('Loc_Sel', Calculate_Train_Weight());
        }

        function Add_Locomotive() {
            Vehicles['Loc']++;
            console.log(Vehicles['Loc']);
            document.getElementById("Button_Div").innerHTML = `<select id="Select_Loc_${Vehicles['Loc']}" > <option>Choose a locomotive</option></select>` + document.getElementById("Button_Div").innerHTML
            //Is doing it once when creating new box enough or should it loop through al existing dropdowns as well?
            Mk_DropDown("Select_Loc_" + Vehicles['Loc'], Locomotives);
        }

        function Add_Wagon() {
            Vehicles['Wag']++;
            document.getElementById("Button_Div").innerHTML += `<select id="Select_Wagon_${Vehicles['Wag']}" > <option>Choose a wagon</option></select>`
            //Is doing it once when creating new box enough or should it loop through al existing dropdowns as well?
            for (let i = 0; i <= Vehicles['Wag']; i++) {
                console.log(i)
                Mk_DropDown("Select_Wagon_" + i, Wagons);
            }
        }

        //This function works but feels like a hack, so if you have suggestions for this feel free to mention it!
        function Reset() {
            document.getElementById("Button_Div").innerHTML = "";
            Vehicles['Loc'] = -1;
            Vehicles['Wag'] = -1;
        }

        Button_Add_Locomotive.addEventListener('click', Add_Locomotive);
        Button_Add_Wagon.addEventListener('click', Add_Wagon);
        Button_Reset.addEventListener('click', Reset);
        Button_Calculate.addEventListener('click', Calculate);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I didn't remove any of the console logs in the code so the console takes up a large part of the section. If you want to run the code snippet I'd recommend clicking the full page option.

Comment: Thanks this is great! How would you implement this in a way which is less jank? I'm trying to learn to code less janky. Also would there be an easy way to keep the selected vehicles when adding another vehicle (Loc/Wag)?

Comment: Also yes I was testing a different implementation in Add_Wagon.