# Weird dropdown menu issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am having a weird issue regarding the `dropdown` menu.

I have

```
company.prototype.buildTable=function(){
  var thisObj=this;

  tableTD = createElement('td');
  tableTD.onclick=function(){thisObj.edit(this);}
  this.table.appendChild(tableTD);  //append td to the table

  // more td

}

company.prototype.edit = function(thisRow) {
  $thisRow=$(thisRow);
  var menu=document.createElement('select');
      menu.className='menu';

   //employees is an array containing employee info

   for(var i=0; i<employees.length; i++){

           var option=document.createElement('option');
               option.className='option';
               option.innerHTML=employees[i].name;
               option.value=employees[i].email;

            menu.appendChild(option);
         }

   $thisRow.append(selectMenu);
}
```

I can see a `dropdown` menu in my td. However, when I click the menu, I had to hold my mouse to
keep options open otherwise the options menu will close. Even if I hold my mouse and select one option,
the `dropdown` menu value wont' change (it still show the first option in the select menu). I hope I explain my issue well.

Can anyone help me with this weird issue?

Comment: Is the issue on appending the `OPTION`s (are they successfully appended?) or is the issue on using the `SELECT`?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, there are some weird cross browser issues with appending options as DOM elements. The preferred way to add options is simply:

```
menu.options[i] = new Option(employees[i].name, employees[i].email);
```

**EDIT**:

[Do not to use appendChild on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611615/are-add-and-appendchild-the-same-for-select-dom-objects) and [do not use innerHTML on select elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738254/javascript-innerhtml-not-working-with-html-select-menus). TL;DR: `HTMLSelectElement` is special and has quirks in IE

Comment: Do you have any sources for that fact?