# SELECT box: On IE item is added to OptGroup instead of root. FF ok

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've got a behaviour a bit strange with `Select` Box and `OptGroup`:
I use `OptGroup` and try to add at the end a single item which I expect to be out of the `OptGroup`. FF does it as expected but IE adds it to the `OptGroup`

With this code : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MBhRk/) (Note: JQuery was just use for the `.ready` method, I can't use it in my project)

```
<select id="selectbox">
    <optgroup label="optGroup1">
        <option>aaaa</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var select = document.getElementById("selectbox");
    option = document.createElement( 'option' );
    option.value = option.text = "test";
    select.add( option );
});
```

---

The result is different in IE and FF

IE:
[image: IE result]
FF:
[image: FF result]

**Note** : I'm using Javascript to add the item because I'm currently using GWT. So this is the way GWT adds an item to a `select`.

Comment: try without: `<optgroup label="optGroup1">` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MBhRk/6/)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Well the whole point is to have groups ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This works](http://jsfiddle.net/q75nV/) in IE and Chrome, so it should work in FF:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var select = document.getElementById("selectbox");
option = document.createElement( 'option' );
option.value = option.text = "test";
select.appendChild( option );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually insert the option *after* option group:

**HTML** (added ID for the Option Group)

```
<select id="selectbox">
    <optgroup label="optGroup1" id="optGroup1">
        <option>aaaa</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var optgroup1 = document.getElementById("optGroup1");
option = document.createElement( 'option' );
option.value = option.text = "test";

//insterting "after"
optgroup1.parentNode.insertBefore(option, optgroup1.nextSibling)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tZ8sz/1/

Comment: Thanks I'll test it in GWT and validate the answer. Don't you think the `add` should work by default ?

Comment: I think it should. I guess Microsoft interprets this differently and by "add" meaning adding to the last group

Comment: I finally went with Pablo answers as I don't have to take care if an optgroup is present or not. But obviously your answer is correct too. Thanks a lot

Comment: No prob. Yes his answer is more streamlined. Btw, since you're already using jQuery, you can ditch getElementById/createElement/appendChild in favour of jQuery methods.